# Which of the following qualifies as a conditional sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditionals

**1) If you step up on this, it could be a great breakthrough for both of you.**

**2) If you stepped up on this, it could be a great breakthrough for both of you.**

Comment: What do you mean "qualifies as conditional"  I'm not sure what you think "a conditional sentence".  Why do you think either of these is or isn't conditional?

Comment: Both of the sentences are conditional.

Comment: The first clause begins with an _if_, and there's a second clause. That makes the sentence a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are conditional.

The first one

> If you step up on this, it could be a great breakthrough for both of you.

is **first conditional**.

While the second one

> If you stepped up on this, it could be a great breakthrough for both of you.

is **second conditional**.

The format of first conditional is: If + present simple, modal verb with future meaning *(shall/should/will/would/can/could/may/might)*

The format of second conditional is: If + past simple, modal verb with future-in-the-past meaning *(should/would/might/could)*

If you would like me to explain these conditionals, just tell me in the comments.